# Restart rails database like Test case with an API call

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

I have a rails application with an API consumed by an Android application.
I want to do integration tests on the Android app, with actual calls to the rails api.
I want that each time a test is executed in the Android app, the rails database is clean again (like what happens when I run tests in the rails app).

Is there anyway that I can restart the database (like in test mode) from an api call?

Comment: It's not an easy problem to solve -- you need to either rebuild the database between calls or do everything in a transaction which you then rollback after the call.  One of the joys of  having an API is that you can unit test the API fully, and it mock it out for client unit testing. So instead of trying to rig up a hefty integration suite that covers lots of cases, it is limited to just making sure the client app actually calls the API. This usually mitigates the need to worry about the data state between calls and you can just refresh the database after the full testing session.

Comment: @dbugger I could mock the API, but in this case I want to do a full integration test. It is a relative small project and in this way I can test that everything is ok.
I like how rails test work so I want to find an strategy to expand this to my full integration tests.